# Windows Server 2003 blocking local port

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2003

I'm using Windows 7. I'm trying to do remote debugging with Visual Studio 2010 on another computer in the same LAN on a Windows 2003 network, but I cannot seem to connect to the other computer (which is running Windows XP Professional)

I disabled the windows firewall on both computers. It uses port 4015. Is it possible that Windows 2003 blocks the port? The network also has a separate firewall, but I think that's only for internet.

Comment: Haha, @Jin – I'm really sorry, I'll let you do your thing!

Comment: @slhck Looks like I got here first :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, its something called IPSec running on a windows 2003 server.